# A Real analysis quesiton related to continuity and completeness

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $I$ be a closed interval and $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Let $c \in f(I), $ and define $S$ to be the set of $x \in I$ such that $f(x)=c$.

```
Show that the set S has a maximum.
```

My prof ask me to assume that the sup of $S$ is not in $S$. However, I have no clue what I should do next.

Thank you for you help!!

Comment: IS $S$ closed or open?

Comment: @EricTowers the question does not indicate if it is open or not.

Comment: Yes it does.  $S$ is the level set of a continuous function.

Comment: Unless $I$ is a closed *bounded* interval, the statement is false. For instance, if $I=[0,\infty\rangle$, you can take the sine function for a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

A more elementary approach: let $M:=\sup S$. Then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $S$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=M$. Since $f$ is continuous, we have:

$$f(M)=f\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=c.$$

So $M\in S$.

**Note:** In order for  $M=\sup S<\infty$, $I$ has to be bounded.

Comment: The condition (cf. @Lubin's comment) that $I$ must be bounded is what guarantees that $\sup S<\infty$ here

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Isn't a closed interval always of the form $[a,b]$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @VincentBoelens depending on the author, the set $[a,\infty)$ may be considered a closed interval.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I wasn't aware of this, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** *I assume in the below that $I$ is supposed to be a **bounded** and closed interval*

It suffices to show that $S$ is a (non-empty) closed subset of $I$.

In fact, we have the following statement that I'm pretty sure you can find somewhere in your analysis textbook:

> **Theorem:** $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if for every open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\{x: f(x) \in U\}$ is open in $D$.

Equivalently, we may state that $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if for every closed set $V \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\{x: f(x) \in V\}$ is closed in $D$.  From there, it suffices to note that the set $\{c\} \subset f(I) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed.

Since $S \subset I$ and $I$ is bounded, $S$ is closed and bounded, which means that it has a maximum and minimum.

Comment: Some people take that to be the definition of continuity.

Comment: Of course we need $S$ to be bounded (think of $\sup \mathbb Z$!), which follws from boundedness of $I$. The latter must be assumed, cf. @Lubin's comment to the question

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thank you for adding this.  I had assumed that OP meant a closed bounded interval and proceeded from there.  An even simpler counterexample to the other case is the constant function $f(x) = c$.